# feel a need or feel the need

Tags: grammar, articles

I am confused as to when to use "a need" and "the need".

> I felt a/the need to take a shower.

With this sentence, we are assuming that there was no mention about the need to take shower before.

I do not think it is defined by first mentioned rule. I am assuming that it depends on the speaker.

If the speaker acknowledges that it is a definite need, that of taking a shower, then he will use "the".

If he feels no need to denote its definiteness and acknowledges that it is told for the first time, he will use "a".

Am I right?

Comment: There is no real difference in meaning between _Feel a need_ and _Feel the need._  No _rule_ is in play here; "feel a need" and "feel the need" are mildly idiomatic in English, and both express only _Need_ or _Want._ In fact, a common definition of the verb _Want_ is _to feel a need or a desire for._

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you! So there is no definiteness involved with "the need"?

Comment: Neither "definiteness" nor "indefiniteness." In this case, "feel a/the need" probably connotes only "need" or "want:" "I needed (or wanted) to take a shower."

Comment: @P.E.Dant What about "there was a/the need to..."? Is it related to definiteness?

Comment: Without context, there's no good answer.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Um, what I'm hoping to find is, if the use of articles can determine definiteness with "there was _need_ to...". Would you use the definite article with that sentence if you are to make it sound definite because the need is known to the listener or if it was mentioned before, etc, and use the indefinite article if you mentioned that need for the first time, or if the listener doesn't know about it, as opposed to no difference in definiteness between _feel a need_ and _feel the need_.

Comment: Yes, the presense of "the" _can_ determine or refer to definiteness, but in a common phrase like _feel the need,_ we would need the complete context to answer that intelligently, @whitedevil .

Comment: @P.E.Dant That is where it is hard. If I say I felt the need to take shower, it is more than probabke I am mentioning it for the first time. But I can use "the" there, because this need is specific. But I can use "a" there too.

Comment: Without context, no. The expression is neutral. It might be used in this context, for instance: _I had not exercised, but I felt the need to take a shower._ Here, there is no difference between that and only: _I had not exercised, but I needed to take a shower._

Comment: @P.E.Dant You mean there is no difference between a need and the need in your sentence? No difference in nuance?

Comment: Yes. No difference.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I must say I am baffled. Is article not a tool to deploy nuance? If there is no difference, what is the use?

Comment: The article is not _always_ used in that way. This is probably the most difficult thing to explain to a non-native speaker: use of the articles. If you present an entire paragraph which contains the phrase _I felt a/the need to take a shower,_ someone could tell you whether one article or the other, or none, signifies something. Without context, it's nearly impossible.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I thought you were saying a need or the need do not make any nuance difference even when a context is provided. –

Comment: No. The opposite. There _may_ be a difference in nuance provided by context. With no context, there is _no difference_ between the sense of the two articles.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Could you show me an example?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Does it follow the standard rule? If this need is mentioned before, we use "the", and if it is introduced for the first time, we use "a"...

Comment: "Feel the/a need" is mildly idiomatic in English, synonymous with _need._ In this phrase, it almost never follows the rule. It probably _could,_ but the context would have to be very specific and I can't think of an example. Google for "feel the need" and read the pages returned.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you, but I meant with the/a need overall, like in this sentence; there was a/the need to perform...blah blah....". What would be some examples with "a" and "the" that show difference in nuance with "there is..." sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question on use "a need" versus "the need" is subtle.
"A" in more general and generic than "the", but often they are interchangeable.

> There is **a** need to improve things.
>   *There is a general desire to improve things*
>
> There is **the** need to improve education.
>   *There is a specific desire to improve schooling*
>
> The company has **a** need for a marketing director.
>   *the company would like to have a marketing director*
>
> The company has **the** need for a marketing director.
>   *the company urgently needs a marketing director*

One of the most famous examples for "the" is

> [I feel the need, the need for speed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O1ZhHts8MI&t=0m14s)